# Passing keyword arguments and **kwargs to subfunction

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, keyword-argument

I have a subclass for executing sql-scripts.

```
def execute_script(self, script_path, **kwargs):
    pass # connect to db
    query = open(script_path, "r").read().format(**kwargs)
    pass # execute script and close connection
```

Depending on what type of action I want to perform, I have different wrapper functions using different keyword arguments, e.g.

```
def create_job(self, **kwargs):
    self.execute_script("create_job.sql", **kwargs)
```

Now, this works perfectly fine for formatting my sql script to include my keyword arguments, if e.g. I execute `create_job(job_name='foo')`. The script gets `job_name` and puts it in my sql script using the `.format()`-method as indicated above.

However, as the sql scripts get longer, and more arguments need to be passed in, I will probably have a harder time remembering exactly which arguments need to be passed down, thus I wanted to switch from `*kwargs` to explicit keyword arguments, like so:

```
def create_job2(self, job_name, **kwargs):
    self.execute_script("create_job.sql", **kwargs)
```

However, this gets me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'job_name'
```

So, I included `job_name`in the subfunction, thinking that the `**kwargs` argument in `execute_script()` means I can pass any amount of keyword arguments into the function.
However,

```
def create_job3(self, job_name, **kwargs):
    self.execute_script("create_job.sql", job_name, **kwargs)
```

results in

```
TypeError: execute_script() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The same error occurs if i leave out the `**kwargs` arguments for the subfunction execute_script()

My question: How can I modify the `execute_script()` function so that I can pass *any* keyword argument into the wrapping function?

*Alternatively* (this would in fact be preferred), can I leave the `**kwargs`-connotation and instead use docstrings or any other mechanism to remind me of the arguments that need to be passed (I am referring to a box popping up and highlighting required arguments, like Sublime Text or PyCharm are doing)?

Comment: With this approach it is very easy to introduce sql injection vulnerabilities. You might want to take a look at *prepared statements* to prevent that.

Comment: Thank you, I have read something similar and changed my code to work with the preferred way `cursor.execute(query, values) - I think this is what you are referring to?

Comment: Exactly, don't format the sql query yourself, i.e. don't use `str.format` or that old `%` string formatting for sql.

Comment: @Wombatz Thank you, it is removed from the string execution.

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
def create_job2(self, job_name, **kwargs):
    self.execute_script("create_job.sql", **kwargs)

def execute_script(self, script_path, **kwargs):
    pass # connect to db
    query = open(script_path, "r").read().format(**kwargs)
    pass # execute script and close connection
```

The `job_name` argument is getting "lost" inside `create_job` and not being passed on to `execute_script`.  `kwargs` is just a mapping that you *could* edit:

```
def create_job2(self, job_name, **kwargs):
    kwargs['job_name'] = job_name
    self.execute_script("create_job.sql", **kwargs)
```

But since you're not actually using `job_name` inside of `create_job`, I don't think breaking it out that way is helpful (and would stick to your original definition of `create_job`).

The `KeyError` indicates that something down the line is expecting either a named argument `job_name`, or you're trying to pull it out of the `kwargs` dict.

As you've noted, one way to "remember" (or be reminded of) the arguments is to explicitly list them in the method definition.

But another is to create a new class, for example:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, name, foo, bar, ...):
        self.name = name
        ...
```

So you have a bunch of arguments in one place which may be annoying and difficult to maintain, but it's only in one place and not repeated in each of your functions.

Then you pass a Job object between functions/methods and they access Job instance attributes.

Depending on your structure, you might even be able to implement a `Job.execute()` method.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Maybe my question was not clear enough; I do not know which arguments will be passed to execute_script(), because it depends on the sql script that I am executing. Editing the kwargs-mapping like you suggested does work, however, once I go past 5 variables the function will get quite chunky. Do you know of a more elegant way to perform this?